# Default template paramters and partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, enable-if

I'm trying to understand partial template specialization with default arguments. If I remove the cast to void in the is_comparable specialization the value printed is always false, while if I keep the cast to (void) things work fine. Can someone please explain why the cast to void is needed? It likely has to do with matching the default template argument for T3, but I'm trying to get some additional insight here into the caveats with template partial specialization and default template parameters.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 = void>
struct is_comparable
{
 static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_comparable<T1, T2, decltype((void)(std::declval<T1>() == std::declval<T2>()))>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
   cout << boolalpha;
   cout << is_comparable<int, char>::value << endl;
   cout << is_comparable<int, float *>::value << endl;
}
```

Update: I observe the same behavior even when pointers are used. I would assume the partial specialization would be picked in this case?

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 = void>
struct is_comparable
{
 static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_comparable<T1*, T2*, decltype((std::declval<T1>() == std::declval<T2>()))>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
   cout << boolalpha;
   cout << is_comparable<int*, int*>::value << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use primary template for default, so

- `is_comparable<int, char>` is `is_comparable<int, char, void>`
- `is_comparable<int, float *>` is `is_comparable<int, float*, void>`
- `is_comparable<int*, int*>` is `is_comparable<int*, int*, void>`

Now, your specialization without void cast is mostly (unless special overload of `operator==`) is

- `is_comparable<T1, T2, bool /* with SFINAE */>`

So doesn't match expected parameters.
You would have to use:

- `is_comparable<int, char, bool>`
- `is_comparable<int, float *, bool>`
- `is_comparable<int*, int*, bool>`

Another way to cast to `void` is `std::void_t`:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename Enabler = void>
struct is_comparable : std::false_type {};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_comparable<T1, T2,
                     std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T1>() == std::declval<T2>())>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler instantiates the primary template and gets the following:

```
is_comparable<int, char, void>
```

Then, in order to select the best match, it tries to instantiate your specialization (assuming there is no typecast `void` and assuming the type substitution succeeds) and gets the following type:

```
is_comparable<int, char, bool>
```

It does not *match* the primary template at all, so it cannot be a better match.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I have updated my question to include a different case of the same problem, namely when both template arguments are int*. In this case I would assume the specialization to be chosen instead but even in this case the primary template is picked.

Comment: From adding more debug info, it looks like it still prefers *is_comparable<T1, T2, T3> [with T1 = int*; T2 = int*; T3 = void]* over the specialization when the 3rd template parameter is *bool* vs. *void*

Comment: @user3882729 again, `is_comparable<int*, char*, bool>` differs from `is_comparable<int*, int*, void>`, so it is not considered!  In order to be a better match, your specialization should *match* the primary template! So either set `bool` as the default argument in the primary template or make this argument `void` in the specialization.